# An SSIS Expression to create a Range

Tags: sql, transform, expression

I am currently working on an HR Reporting project. I have a column in the report labeled [YearsService] that details how many years of service the employee had from the time they were hired to Term date.

```
YearsService
0.25
1.02
2.45
3.21
5.25
5.14
9.75
25.12
```

What I want to do is to enter an expression that adds a column that details a range.

```
YearsService     YearsServiceName
0.25             < 11.99 Months
1.02             1 - 2.99 yrs
2.45             2 - 4.99 yrs
3.21             2 - 4.99 yrs
5.25             5 - 7.99 yrs
5.14             5 - 7.99 yrs
9.75             8 - 9.99 yrs
25.12            10 + years
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to write that expression? Will a variable be better?
Also 
Those employees that have not been termed have a 0.00 showing. I am sure can just run an expression to remove these and make them NULL but am open to other ideas if anyone has any.

This report is being imported from a .XLS file and transformed. It's then being accessed by another .XLS file in the form of a data connection and pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

I decided that the best solution for this was to CAST the column  in the view for the range(s) I needed and create a new column labeled [YrsServName]

Here is the script I used.

```
CASE WHEN Staging.EEMaster.YearsService > 0 AND 
Staging.EEMaster.YearsService < 1 THEN '< - 11.99 Months' WHEN 
Staging.EEMaster.YearsService > 0.99 AND Staging.EEMaster.YearsService < 3 THEN '1 - 2.99 Years' WHEN 
Staging.EEMaster.YearsService > 2.99 AND
Staging.EEMaster.YearsService < 5 THEN '3 - 4.99 Years' WHEN
Staging.EEMaster.YearsService > 4.99 AND Staging.EEMaster.YearsService < 8 THEN '5 - 7.99 Years' WHEN 
Staging.EEMaster.YearsService > 7.99 AND 
Staging.EEMaster.YearsService < 10 THEN '8 - 9.99 Years' WHEN  
Staging.EEMaster.YearsService > 9.99 THEN '10+ Years' END AS YrsServName
```

Hopefully this will help someone else that may need this.